# Conditioning the orderBy filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to but a condition before applying the `orderBy` filter.
My filter looks like:

```
orderBy:sortBy.Name:order.reverse
```

I want to apply the filter in case the `sortBy.name != "None"`.
Can you help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: See last example in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy (use a function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good tutorial for this:
http://www.jacopretorius.net/2013/05/custom-sorting-in-angularjs.html

Where instead of the random sort function, you will want something like:

```
$scope.randomSort = function(item) {
  if(item.name = "None")
    {return "";}
  else
   {return item.name;}
};
```

By returning an empty string instead of name in your sort, it will put these items at the start.

Comment: Hello @Sam I just implemented the filter like you suggested and it works. A slight change I made, was in `orderBy` call after `ng-repeat`: | `...| orderBy:hotelSortBy() | ...`. I needed to put the `()` after the function name. Thanks :)